# C# gRPC Server freezes when clients make stream requests

Tags: c#, grpc

I'm running a gRPC server that has several different streaming services.

When connecting multiple clients, the server freezes for about one minute before allowing the applications to continue with the requests.

The problem is just when clients connect, after that it all works with no hiccups.

Is there a way to improve that?

I added a log to check the connections and when it is a single client is fine.

The more clients I add the longer it takes to allow the server to run.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It's very hard to know whether there's a problem with the code when we can't *see* any code.

Comment: found a solution or a reason? Having the same issue but with infinite server freezes. On my side a client threading issue (deadlock) is causing the issue.